# Tools to create a reporting website in .NET?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

I want to create a reporting website and if coding is required, I am familiar with C#. I saw people talking about Crystal Reports but wasn't clear whether it can work well in .NET web application. Besides Crystal, what are the other options? Is there simply a "database browser" web app that only requires a DB connection and all other customization is optional? Sorry for the stupid questions, I have zero experience in reporting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem,
It is depend on the report type that do you want to display and data quality that you want to achieve.

You can use traditional spreadsheet like utilizing for MS Excel or other spreadsheet software for half baken report. This report style can be further use or data feed for another report.
This techniques is easy since most of report generated is csv files or xml files that can be imported in spreadsheet.

You can use like Crystal report or report viewer from Microsoft (SQL Server or report viewer). This is an easy way to create report since it intend as presentation or end user support. You can drill down to its detail using report viewer but I suggest you use spreadsheet to do some report operation like pivoting or something.

In this case you concern about data quality too. is it half baken solution;to be processed later; or need cleansing using ETL?

You can use various tools or software like business intelligent tool from Microsoft SQL Server, or IBM tools or oracle tools to do that. There are many of them taht suite to your needs and can be integrate to your software.

If you want a database browser, you can download VS 2010 with SP1 and EF 4.1. I forget the web project template that can use as insert update delete and it is already created for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [Report Viewer for SQL Server Reporting Services](http://reportviewer.codeplex.com/) or [ReportViewer](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/).